# Tricks for using the rune stones?

Tags: dragons-crown

Are there any tricks for using the rune stones that appear in the game? The first one was mostly easy because there was just one and it was required to progress. But now that I've obtained 4 stones it seems like just trial and error when activating these scattered stones (that are hard to notice in the first place). Basically is there a way to know which stone to use to complete the combination or are there cases where multiple stones on the same runes have different effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than trial and error, check the rune's form and use that as a hint. Memory based, rune combinations result in a spell with a name formed by three letters, where each selected rune represents the first letter of each word.

Some examples:

- Dead Be Gone
- Enchanted Coin Geyser
- Call Sylphide's Wind
- The Skeleton Key

You can always [use a chart](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140511233331/dragons-crown/images/9/9d/Runes.png) when in doubt, there's not an autocomplete function. Also, remember that there are no multiple combinations, but the runes can be tapped in any order.

Comment: I haven't played this in awhile but never noticed this. That's pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

You can talk to Merlin to check the spells you've already discovered. I believe he also shows you a list of all the valid rune combinations (but doesn't tell you their effects until you actually cast the spell somewhere). The game is designed for you to "stumble upon" the rune words through some trial and error, though.